# Passing single quoted param to js function dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Am facing issue in handling single quotes in JavaScript function dynamically. Here is my code,

```
<logic: iterate ...   >
    <a onclick= "funcName('<bean:write name="Username"/>')"> Click Me </a>
</logic: iterate>
```

This code breaks when username has single quotes in it(O'Brien / B'sinn). Am having this inside logic: iterate, so can't assign it to variable first and do escape char. I've seen few similar ques ,but that doesn't helps.